# Why is subclass member not protected?

Tags: java, inheritance

Why is v.v accessible if MyTest is not a parent-class of Val?

```
public class MyTest 
{
    public static void main (String args [])
    {
        ValX v = new ValX ();
        System.out.println ("A: " + v.v);  // is working, why?
    }
}


public class ValX extends Val
{
}


public class Val 
{
    protected float v = 11;
}
```

**EDIT**

I learned about the visibility of proteced within the package. Thats the reason. thanks!

Is there a way I can make v only visible to parent-classes without moving it to another package?

Comment: Because MyTest is in the same package as ValX. Protected access also gives package access.

Comment: The float *is* protected. Protected variables can be accessed by every Class in the same package and any subclass. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/215497/in-java-difference-between-package-private-public-protected-and-private

Comment: more than one `?` won't make us think harder about your problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Java, visibility levels form a completely ordered chain of inclusion.

A `private` member can only be seen from within the current class.

A `package-private` member can only be seen from within the current package, which the current class is a part of.

A `protected` member can only be seen from subclasses **or from the current package**, thus covering everything that package-private can see.

And a `public` member can be seen from everywhere.

Since your class MyTest is in the same package as Val, the `protected` visibility grants access.